# define new macro to add "title" attribute

Tags: math-mode, macros, html, mathjax

I'm using MathJax on my website and I want to add some semantic support.

Currently, my MathJax configuration is to take TeX input and spit out HTML-CSS output (unfortunately MathML doesn't work too well in Chrome). I also have a jQuery function that takes the html of any `.latex` class and dumps it into the `title` attribute.

The following HTML...

```
<div class="latex">\[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \]</div>
```

with the following script...

```
/* jQuery */
$('.latex').attr('title', function() {
    return $(this).html();
})
```

will output...

```
<div class="latex" title="\[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \]">
    <div class="MathJax_Display">a2+b2=c2</div> <!-- becomes prettyprint in browser -->
</div>
```

Obviously the contents of `div.MathJax_Display` will be styled with a whole slew of spans and classes and styles. I'm just not going to type all that here. Anyway, after the math is rendered, users can hover over `div.latex` to see the TeX commands in a tooltip.

Now, what I want to do is define a new macro in my MJ configuration that will add a `title` attribute to a newly-created span of HTML-CSS output, given a bit of TeX input. Let's call that macro `\title[2]`. Here's what I want to be able to input:

```
<div class="latex">\[ a^2 + b^2 = \title{c}{'hypotenuse'}^2 \]</div>
```

And here's what I want it to output:

```
<div class="latex" title="\[ a^2 + b^2 = \title{c}{'hypotenuse'}^2 \]">
    <div class="MathJax_Display">a2+b2=<span title="hypotenuse">c</span>2</div> <!-- prettyprint -->
</div>
```

If this happens, users who hover over the `c` in the math will get a tooltip that says "hypotenuse", but hover over any other area of the math and get the original input.

Here's my thinking for the algorithm:

```
//pseudo-code: 
given the TeX input '\title{mathstr}{titlestr}':
  var thespan = document.createElement('span');
  $(thespan).attr('title', titlestr).html(mathstr);
  somehow put this into the MJ output at the right place
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `action` extension that defines `\texttip` and `\mathtip` for attaching tooltips to subexpressions?  See the [MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#action) for details.

Comment: The downside to this macro is that it's written in JavaScript, not HTML, so (1) users who have JS disabled (and will still be able to see the original TeX input) will not be able to see the tooltip, and (2) nested `\mathtip` commands results in UNDERlapping, not overlapping. In other words, JS will display the tooltip of the outermost span. On the flip side, HTML `title` attributes will OVERlap, meaning that the innermost element's tooltip gets displayed. I accepted your answer because it's right, but it doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: I just figured this out... using `\mathtip` uses JS to create tooltip-looking boxes that underlap, so there's no point in nesting them. But `\texttip` actually creates `title` attributes in the HTML, so they act like normal tooltips, which do overlap. You just can't put any math in them, even with the `\(` and `\)` delimiters, otherwise they'll be turned into the imposter tooltips.

Comment: Nested `\mathtip` calls work fine for me.  What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: You are correct about the difference between `\texttip` and `\mathtip`.  This is because the contents of an HTML tooltip can only be text, not HTML, and since math requires HTML layout, you can't use HTML tooltips for it.  So MathJax has to implement its own tooltips for math content.

Comment: I don't understand your complaint (1) about using javascript for this.  Your original `<div class="latex">\[ a^2 + b^2 = \title{c}{'hypotenuse'}^2 \]</div>` also would not show tooltips if javascript is turned off.  The only thing that is different is the name of the macro.  Perhaps I misunderstand your complaint.